# Cartesian product SQL

Tags: product, cartesian

I have searched in other questions but I don't really get how to get the correct amount and not the cartesian product.

I have the following table:

```
EGAIT6  EGACAM      EGVONO   ACC
2477717 -1443,87    41300015 2995
2477717 -2424,75    41300021 2995
2477717 -26630,16   41300022 2995
2477717   22652,96  41563318 2995
2477717   14513,12  41566334 2995
2477717   7703,08   41566335 2995
2477717   1443,87   41566336 2995
2477717   2482,70   41566338 2995
2477717   1124,84   41566339 2995
2477717   4610,99   41566337 2995
2477717    393,45   41571055 2995
2477717    393,45   41571056 2995
2477717    344,04   41574437 2995
2477717    344,04   41574438 2995
2477717    344,04   41584940 2995
2477717    344,04   41584941 2995
2477717    225,70   41689722 2995
2477717   1814,75   41726904 2995
2477717   1814,75   41726905 2995
```

This is my Query:

```
select 
    a.egait6, 
    sum(a.egacam), 
    a.egvono, 
    max(a.egvtxt), 
    max(a.egacdt)
from m3prd.fgledg a
inner join m3prd.fgledg b
    on a.egait6 = b.egait6 
where a.egcono=001 
    and a.egdivi='012' 
    and a.egait1='2995' 
    and a.egait6='2477717'
group by a.egait6, a.egvono
having sum(a.egacam)<>0
```

I get the following result:

```
EGAIT6     EGACAM   EGVONO
2477717 6 880,80    41574437
2477717 49 654,00   41566338
2477717 6 880,80    41584940
2477717 290 262,40  41566334
2477717 36 295,00   41726905
2477717 92 219,80   41566337
2477717 -532 603,20 41300022
2477717 154 061,60  41566335
2477717 7 869,00    41571056
2477717 6 880,80    41574438
2477717 22 496,80   41566339
2477717 36 295,00   41726904
2477717 -48 495,00  41300021
2477717 4 514,00    41689722
2477717 453 059,20  41563318
2477717 6 880,80    41584941
2477717 -28 877,40  41300015
2477717 7 869,00    41571055
2477717 28 877,40   41566336
```

How do I get my Query to return the correct amount according ty my table, and not the cartesian Product?

The correct amount, expected value in amount is:

```
EGACAM
-  1 443,87
-  2 424,75
-  26 630,16
22 652,96
14 513,12
7 703,08
1 443,87
2 482,70
1 124,84
4 610,99
393,45
393,45
344,04
344,04
344,04
344,04
225,70
1 814,75
1 814,75
```

I am mamking a self join becaus the real table I'm searching in has more and different values in both EGAIT6 and EGVONO. So I can't erase that part of the Query. I just want to know how to avoid getting the cartesian Product as a result.

Comment: What amount are you expecting to get?

Comment: What exactly is "the correct amount"? Not only do you never say this explicitly, your field names make it hard to infer this as well.

Comment: You're joining the table to itself, using the exact same field in "both" tables. why shouldn't it be doing this?

Comment: You're doing a self-join on a column that only has the same value for every row in it, so of course you get a Cartesian product.

Answer (score -1):

remove these lines:

```
inner join m3prd.fgledg b
on a.egait6 = b.egait6
```

I can't see any use for making a join on the same table....